# SQL Server Production behaving differently than developer version. Encoding is suspect!

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode, encoding

**Given:**

A very large XML file that is loaded into a table using the `nvarchar(max)` datatype. This results in doubling the size of the data (probably due to SQL Server encoding to unicode) and then later on we read the file from the table, parse it and do a bulk insert into other tables in the database.

**Problem:**

On the development sever, this works fine and there are no issues. However, upon attempting to bulk insert on a production server, I receive the following error:

> Exception:System.InvalidOperationException:
>   The given value of type String from
>   the data source cannot be converted to
>   type nvarchar of the specified target
>   column. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   String or binary data would be
>   truncated.

A couple of peculiar things I have noticed:
When ftp-ing an ANSI version of the Xml file (to be read later by the web app) it adds a few bytes to the file and then DOUBLES in size when inserted into our table. When ftp-ing a unicode version, the bytes remain the same but it also DOUBLES and then fails miserably

```
b e c a u s e  t h e  d a t a  s t a r t s  t o  l o o k  l i k e  t h i s.
```

We ruled out bad data by stripping down the XML to one record under the root. Development handled it, production did not.

Something **MUST** be different between the configuration in our developement and production servers but we can't figure it out. Collation is the same by the way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** An Update: We tried reading the file into the `XmlDocument` object directly from the server and bypassing the process of storing it to the db. No change in behavior.

**Second Update:** We ruled out the FTP process (maybe?) by copying the file over and then BACK (file size shinks by a few bytes but we get those bytes back upon copying it back over).

Comment: would you demonstrate some of the code that you are using to load the file into sql?

Comment: How big is the "very large XML file"?

Comment: @Peter I'll see if I can add something when I get into work. @Martin, very large is 65MB but this occurs even when I strip down the xml to one record (apprx 3KB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was a new instance of the application, dropping the two tables and re-adding them fixed the problem (this was done using SQL Compare).

This was how **I** solved the problem but I believe Marc Gravell is on to something.

Answer (score 3):

The "truncated" warning suggests to me that in production the column is not, in fact, `max` - but rather something like `nvarchar(4000)` (the old maximum before you had to go to `ntext`).

Verify that the column is in fact `max`.

As a side note, if you are only **storing** the data, `varbinary(max)` would be preferred - it will avoid the doubling etc. And if you are **inspecing** the data, `xml` might be preferred.

Comment: +1 We fixed the problem (see my answer) but I believe that your input is important to note. The person who owns the software doesn't want us to use the XML datatype because he believes that may add an unnecessary constraint to the input we provide which would cause problems if the XML is not well-formed. I'm not sure how SQL Server Xml data type handles malformed XML so I didn't bother pushing him on this.

Comment: @DJTriple it would be rejected at the server

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Later on, I may refactor the code and make this field `varbinary(max)` because as you said, we are only storing the data. In production, It typically gets read once and then discarded in a clean up process sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

The collation of the *column* is what matters. The collation of the *table, database*, and even the collation setting of the *SQL Server itself* simply define what default collation will be used the next time a new column is created.

As you can imagine, its not uncommon to end up with single columns set to the wrong collation value.

Pinal Dave has several useful scripts on his blog, including [this one which allows you to see the current collation settings of columns](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/16/sql-server-find-collation-of-database-and-table-column-using-t-sql/):

```
/* Find Collation of SQL Server Database */
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('AdventureWorks', 'Collation')
GO
/* Find Collation of SQL Server Database Table Column */
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE type = 'U'
    AND name = 'Address')
    AND name = 'City'
```

Also a very comprehensive [follow-up post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/19/sql-server-change-collation-of-database-column-t-sql-script-consolidating-collations-extention-script/) with an entire set of scripts (written by Brian Cidern) that allow you to identify and resolve collation conflicts.